# Creating a Game Map

Tags: javascript, game, touch

I'm trying to make a kind of Dungeon Keeper clone. I got the code up and running and even supporting touch events. But I don't think it's as well optimized as it could be, so I am looking for help and best practices on helping improve my map.

You can test it out and play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dethstrobe/w6gtLtwc/9/) or for [full screen here](https://jsfiddle.net/dethstrobe/w6gtLtwc/9/embedded/result/).

It runs perfectly on my local machine and iPhone, but using it from JSFiddle seems to cause some problems. I'm not sure if it's a problem with JSFiddle or if my localhost plays more fast and loose with JavaScript.

```
 var CanvasDisplay = function (parent, level) {
     this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
     parent.appendChild(this.canvas);
     this.cx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

     this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mapMove);
     this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.mapSelect);
     //wheel event for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
     this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("mousewheel", this.mapZoom);
     //wheel event for Firefox
     this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", this.mapZoom);

     //touch events
     this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", this.mapTouchStart);
     this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", this.mapMoveTouch);

     this.touch = {
         x: null,
         y: null,
         hypotenuse: null
     };

     this.level = {
         height: level.length,
         width: level[0].length,
         scale: 100
     };

     this.view = {
         x: this.canvas.width / 2 - (this.level.width * this.level.scale / 2),
         y: this.canvas.height / 2 - (this.level.height * this.level.scale / 2),
         width: this.canvas.width,
         height: this.canvas.height,

         move: false,
         select: {}
     };
 };

 CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapSelect = function (event) {
     if (display.view.move === true) {
         display.view.move = false;
         return;
     }

     var pos = display.relativePos(event, this);

     var tileLoc = {
         x: Math.floor((pos.x - display.view.x) / display.level.scale),
         y: Math.floor((pos.y - display.view.y) / display.level.scale)
     };

     if (typeof basicMap[tileLoc.y] !== 'undefined' && typeof basicMap[tileLoc.y][tileLoc.x] !== 'undefined') display.view.select = tileLoc;
     else display.view.select = {};

     renderMap(basicMap, display);

     event.preventDefault();
 };

 CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapZoom = function (event) {
     var pos = display.relativePos(event, this);
     var currentScale = display.level.scale;
     var posFromEdge = {
         x: display.view.x - pos.x,
         y: display.view.y - pos.y
     };

     if (event.wheelDelta > 0 && display.level.scale < 200 || -event.detail > 0 && display.level.scale < 200) {
         display.level.scale += 10;
         display.zoomOnCenter(display, currentScale, posFromEdge, pos);
     } else if (event.wheelDelta < 0 && display.level.scale > 50 || -event.detail < 0 && display.level.scale > 50) {
         display.level.scale -= 10;
         display.zoomOnCenter(display, currentScale, posFromEdge, pos);
     }

     renderMap(basicMap, display);

     event.preventDefault();
 };

 CanvasDisplay.prototype.zoomOnCenter = function (display, currentScale, posFromEdge, pos) {

     var diffScale = display.level.scale / currentScale;

     display.view.x = posFromEdge.x * diffScale + pos.x;
     display.view.y = posFromEdge.y * diffScale + pos.y;
 };

 //return location of curser of click
 CanvasDisplay.prototype.relativePos = function (event, element) {
     var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
     return {
         x: Math.floor(event.clientX - rect.left),
         y: Math.floor(event.clientY - rect.top)
     };
 };

 CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapTouchStart = function (event) {
     var display = display;
     //move map if there is only 1 finger
     if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
         var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

         display.touch.x = touch.pageX;
         display.touch.y = touch.pageY;
     } else if (event.targetTouches.length == 2) {
         var touch1 = event.targetTouches[0],
             touch2 = event.targetTouches[1];
         display.touch.hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(touch1.pageX * touch1.pageX + touch2.pageX * touch2.pageX);
         display.touch.x = (touch1.pageX + touch2.pageX) / 2;
         display.touch.y = (touch1.pageY + touch2.pageY) / 2;
     }
 };

 CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapMoveTouch = function (event) {
     //move map if there is only 1 finger
     if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
         var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
         var viewPos = display.view;

         viewPos.x += touch.pageX - display.touch.x;
         viewPos.y += touch.pageY - display.touch.y;

         display.touch.x = touch.pageX;
         display.touch.y = touch.pageY;

         //zoom map if there are 2 fingers
     } else if (event.targetTouches.length == 2) {
         var touch1 = event.targetTouches[0];
         var touch2 = event.targetTouches[1];

         var hypo = Math.sqrt(touch1.pageX * touch1.pageX + touch2.pageX * touch2.pageX);
         var hypoDiff = hypo - display.touch.hypotenuse;

         var posFromEdge = {
             x: display.view.x - display.touch.x,
             y: display.view.y - display.touch.y
         };
         var currentScale = display.level.scale;

         if (hypoDiff > 0 && display.level.scale < 200) {
             display.level.scale += hypoDiff;
             display.zoomOnCenter(display, currentScale, posFromEdge, display.touch);
         } else if (hypoDiff < 0 && display.level.scale > 50) {
             display.level.scale += hypoDiff;
             display.zoomOnCenter(display, currentScale, posFromEdge, display.touch);
         }

         display.touch.hypotenuse = hypo;

     }
     event.preventDefault();

     renderMap(basicMap, display);
 };

 CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapMove = function (event) {
     if (event.which == 1) {

         //do onMove function on mousemove
         var trackDrag = function (onMove) {
             function end(event) {
                 removeEventListener("mousemove", onMove);
                 removeEventListener("mouseup", end);
             }
             addEventListener("mousemove", onMove);
             addEventListener("mouseup", end);
         };

         var canvas = this;
         var pos = display.relativePos(event, canvas);
         var viewPos = display.view;

         trackDrag(function (event) {
             var currentPos = pos;
             var newPos = display.relativePos(event, canvas);

             display.view.x = viewPos.x + newPos.x - currentPos.x;
             display.view.y = viewPos.y + newPos.y - currentPos.y;
             renderMap(basicMap, display);

             display.view.move = true;
             pos = newPos;
         });


         event.preventDefault();
     }
 };

 var tileKey = {
     x: 'black',
     _: 'blue',
         ' ': 'white',
     t: 'green'
 };

 var readableMap = [
     "x_xxxx_x",
     "x      x",
     "x  tt  x",
     "x      x",
     "xxx__xxx"];

 var display = new CanvasDisplay(document.getElementById('game'), readableMap);

 window.onresize = function () {
     display.view.width = display.cx.canvas.width = display.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     display.view.height = display.cx.canvas.height = display.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

     renderMap(basicMap, display);
 };

 var mapGenerator = function (readableMap) {
     return readableMap.map(function (line) {
         return line.split('').map(function (character) {
             return {
                 type: tileKey[character]
             };
         });
     });
 };

 var basicMap = mapGenerator(readableMap);

 var renderMap = function (mapArr, display) {

     var mapLimits = function (axis, dimension) {
         var levelLength = display.level[dimension] * display.level.scale,
             levelPaddedLength = levelLength + display.level.scale * 2,
             levelDifference = display.view[dimension] - levelLength,
             levelEnd = -(levelLength - display.view[dimension] + display.level.scale);

         if (levelPaddedLength < display.view[dimension]) {

             if (display.view[axis] < 0) {
                 display.view[axis] = 0;
             } else if (display.view[axis] > levelDifference) {
                 display.view[axis] = levelDifference;
             }

         } else {

             if (display.view[axis] > display.level.scale) {
                 display.view[axis] = display.level.scale;
             } else if (display.view[axis] < levelEnd) {
                 display.view[axis] = levelEnd;
             }

         }
     };

     mapLimits("x", "width");
     mapLimits("y", "height");

     display.cx.clearRect(0, 0, display.cx.canvas.width, display.cx.canvas.height);

     var location = function (arrLoc, displayLoc) {
         return arrLoc * display.level.scale + display.view[displayLoc];
     };

     mapArr.forEach(function (line, y) {
         line.forEach(function (tile, x) {
             display.cx.fillStyle = tile.type;
             display.cx.fillRect(location(x, "x"), location(y, "y"), display.level.scale, display.level.scale);

             if (Object.keys(display.view.select).length !== 0) {
                 display.cx.strokeStyle = "gold";
                 display.cx.strokeRect(location(display.view.select.x, "x"), location(display.view.select.y, "y"), display.level.scale, display.level.scale);
             }
         });
     });
 };

 renderMap(basicMap, display);
```

Comment: That all looks really pretty straightforward.  Is there a particular section of it that you think might be a trouble spot?  Other than pointing out some things that would just gain a few cycles, such as using triple === consistently, I don't really see a lot.  There's the annoyance that for a large array, a standard for loop is usually faster than a forEach, and that Object.keys() can be more expensive than other methods of checking for presence of data, but those are really minor nits for something like this i'd guess.

Comment: One of my big concerns is that I'm calling display.someMethod a lot. Because I'm calling a method on the same object, but `this` refers to the canvas element, I was wondering if there was a better way to access methods on the same object.

Comment: Even if "this" is pointing to that particular CanvasDisplay instance, rather than the Canvas, there's still not really an optimization there.  Would be clearer to read, though.  I'd have to actually step through it to verify that "this" isn't what you expect, I think it would be, based on how you've constructed everything there.  (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I am expecting `this` to be the canvas on my eventlisteners, but I want to access methods that are on the same object.

I assume there is no way to call a method from within another method. Or maybe its frivolous and doesn't matter.

Comment: Ahhhh, OK. Right, the event handlers.  You could this.cx.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mapMove.bind(this)); and then "this" in Constructor becomes "this" when mapMove is called.  I'd say it's a readability concern, rather than a performance concern.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of public fields.

By that, I mean that you set a lot of properties of the `CanvasDisplay` class to public (you use the `this` keyword to create them).

It is better practice make as many properties as you can private. That means that you use the `var` keyword when you create them, and that you just reference to them as their name **without** the `this` keyword.

---

In a couple of the methods of `CanvasDisplay`, you catch an event and call `preventDefault` to stop it from performing it's default behavior.

I'm unsure if this will make a difference, but it might be better to move that function call to the very top of the function; that way (I think) the default behavior of the event is more likely to not be executed

---

In the function `end` of the function `trackDrag` of the function `CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapMove`, you have a parameter to catch the event that is fired when the function is fired.

Although, you don't use that event variable any where in that function.

---

In the function `CanvasDisplay.prototype.mapSelect`, in the first conditional of the function, if it passes, you just `return`.

You don't return any value.

In that situation, it would be better practice to return `null`, rather than to not return anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll see about making those changes.

Comment: @Dethstrobe Do not put those changes in your answer. Read [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.